# SQLite IFF to change results returns

Tags: sqlite, iif

I'm querying a table with a column that has 5 possible values (1111A, 2222B, 3333C, 4444D, 5555E), I would like to rename those results as part of my query so for each of my results, result should be display as follows:

1111A should be renamed to Red
2222B should be renamed to Blue
You get the picture.

Is this something I could achieve using IIF? If so, an example would be greatly appreciated. If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean something like `update table_name set col_name = case col_name when '1111A' then 'Red' when '2222B' then 'Blue' when '3333C' then 'You' else 'Get The Picture' end;` ?

Comment: Thanks Anon, but no, I just want to change the query results on the fly. Something like 1111a would not make sense to the audience I'm sharing the query results with.

Comment: So, then, just `select case col_name when '1111A' then 'Red' when '2222B' then 'Blue' when '3333C' then 'You' else 'Get The Picture' end as col_name from table_name;`, or just a normal inner join?